# Disable gnuplot's font antialiasing

Tags: fonts, gnuplot, antialiasing

No matter what I do, gnuplot always seems to use antialiasing when rendering fonts. Is there any way to prevent gnuplot from doing this?

I suspect there is a way because the 3D plot at the top right at http://www.gnuplot.info/ has no font antialiasing. Unfortunately that is the only plot I have found that looks like this and there is no hint how that plot was created.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering why you wish to turn off that feature. But here is a section from the gnuplot manual:

> The rendering of the plot cannot be altered yet. To obtain the best output possible, the rendering
>   involves two mechanisms : antialiasing and oversampling. Antialiasing allows to display non-horizontal
>   and non-vertical lines smoother. Oversampling combined with antialiasing provides subpixel accuracy,
>   so that gnuplot can draw a line from non-integer coordinates. This avoids wobbling eects on diagonal
>   lines ('plot x' for example).

The only thing I can think of what might lead to a solution for you is to try different gnuplot terminals. For example:

```
set term pdfcairo
set output "Test.pdf"
test
```

Then you can check if the output satisfies your needs.

Comment: Subjective reason: font antialiasing is too ugly to me. Objective reason: It will make png file size larger. Example: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Fyb8b.png - Antialiasing, size=5632; http://i.stack.imgur.com/FeT9R.png - No-antialiasing, size=5089.  Size ratio: 110%.   >> why you wish to turn off that feature

Answer (score 0):

The Anti-aliasing can be controlled on some terminals:

For example, for the wxt terminal (the default terminal - at least on linux):

> The rendering of the plot can be
>   altered with a dialog available from
>   the  toolbar. To obtain the best
>   output possible, the rendering
>   involves three  mechanisms :
>   antialiasing, oversampling and
>   hinting.

Its controlled from the spanner icon in the plot window.

I'm not sure how possible it is for the other terminals

Comment: Yes, but that only alters the appearance of the plot. The rendering of fonts for axes labels are not affected by these settings.

Comment: @lmar If you just want to control the font then you could try epslatex terminal. This makes two files - one eps with the graph, and one latex file to put it in. You can then use latex to control the founts as you please (they will be same as the document you put the graph in).